# Passar variavel no UPDATE PDO PHPERRO: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]

Tags: php, query, pdo, sql-update

```
@$c_matricula = $_POST['numero'];
@$data_aa = $_POST['data_aa'];
@$data_ff = $_POST['data_ff'];

if(isset($data_aa)){

    @$dataa = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $pdo = $dbconn->prepare("UPDATE contato SET c_data_andamento = :data_a WHERE c_matricula = :c_matricula");
    // $stmt->bindParam(':data_a', $data_a);
    // $stmt->bindParam(':c_matricula', $c_matricula);
    $pdo->execute();

// header("Location: listar_contato.php");
}

else

{

    $pdo = $dbconn->prepare("UPDATE contato SET c_data_finalizado=:data_f WHERE c_matricula = :numero");
    $pdo->execute();
```

Estou recebendo um *post* de outra pagina, se esse *post* existir preciso executar uma *query* passando a data atual, caso contrário eu passo outra *query*.

> ```
> Erro:Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound in C:\xampp\htdocs\programacao\avanco_contato.php on line 34
> ```

Comment: e qual é o problema?

Comment: O php estoura um erro falando que o parâmetro e invalido

Comment: quem é `$data_a`? qual é a linha 34? Porque os  `bindParam` estão comentados? Em `$stmt->bindParam(':data_a', $data_a)` é esperado `$data_a` que está ausente no seu código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@$c_id = "2";
@$c_data_andamento = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

 $pdo = $dbconn->prepare("UPDATE contato SET c_data_andamento = :c_data_andamento WHERE c_id = :c_id");
    $pdo->bindParam(':c_data_andamento', $c_data_andamento);
    $pdo->bindParam(':c_id', $c_id);
    $pdo->execute();
```